# getnameinfo specifies socklen_t

Tags: c, linux, networking, posix, socklen-t

The 2nd arg for the getnameinfo prototype asks for a socklen_t type but sizeof uses size_t. So how can I get socklen_t ?

Prototype:

```
int getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr *restrict sa, socklen_t salen,
       char *restrict node, socklen_t nodelen, char *restrict service,
       socklen_t servicelen, int flags);
```

Example:

```
struct sockaddr_in SIN;
memset(&SIN, 0, sizeof(SIN)); // This should also be socklen_t ?
SIN.sin_family      = AF_INET;
SIN.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
SIN.sin_port        = 0;

getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&SIN, sizeof(SIN) /* socklen_t */, BUFFER, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
```

This will give compiler error:

```
socklen_t VAR;
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&SIN, &VAR, BUFFER, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is `sizeof` by itself causing a problem?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: No problem or compiler error but I guess that if getnameinfo asks for socklen_t I should not pass size_t...

Comment: There are worse things in life to worry about. I have never seen socket code that bothers about this.

Comment: I always provide what the prototype asks for. Best practise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`size_t` [is defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t) as an unsigned integral type; C99 guarantees that it is at least 16 bits.

`socklen_t` [is defined](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) as an integral type of at least 32 bits.  (**Edit:** It's not necessarily unsigned, although in practice a negative length would be meaningless.)

So there's no problem with passing a `size_t` parameter and letting the compiler implicitly cast it to `socklen_t`, and I would argue that it makes your code clearer to let the implicit conversion occur instead of adding pedantic casts.

Your final example

```
socklen_t VAR;
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&SIN, &VAR, BUFFER, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
```

gives a compiler error because you're passing a pointer-to-a-socken_t instead of a socklen_t.

Comment: More to the point, the value returned by `sizeof` for any `sockaddr` type structure will always fit into a `socklen_t` type, so the conversion is safe.

Answer (score 2):

(This is rather an answer to [this IMHO falsely duplicate-tagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222562/why-does-inet-ntop-use-socklen-t-to-describe-size-of-textual-buffer) that tries to get to the bottom of `socklen_t`'s existence.)

As others have pointed out it can be thought of as the `size_t` equivalent of the POSIX Sockets API that represents the length of various data structures in bytes. It is most notable in the `bind()`, `listen()`, `connect()` functions where it denotes the length of the various implementations of `struct sockaddr` but it is not limited to that at all.

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_10_06) actually explains how it became to be and is very instructive IMHO:

> The type `socklen_t` was invented to cover the range of implementations seen in the field. The intent of `socklen_t` is to be the type for all lengths that are naturally bounded in size; that is, that they are the length of a buffer which cannot sensibly become of massive size: network addresses, host names, string representations of these, ancillary data, control messages, and socket options are examples. Truly boundless sizes are represented by `size_t` as in `read()`, `write()`, and so on.
>
> All `socklen_t` types were originally (in BSD UNIX) of type `int`. During the development of POSIX.1-2008, it was decided to change all buffer lengths to `size_t`, which appears at face value to make sense. When dual mode 32/64-bit systems came along, this choice unnecessarily complicated system interfaces because `size_t` (with long) was a different size under ILP32 and LP64 models. Reverting to `int` would have happened except that some implementations had already shipped 64-bit-only interfaces. The compromise was a type which could be defined to be any size by the implementation: `socklen_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Your information are out of date, socklen_t is an integer type (not necesarily unsigned) of at least 32 bits (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html).