# Why does inet_ntop() use socklen_t to describe size of textual buffer?

Tags: c, network-programming, size-t, socklen-t

From a recent Linux man-page:

> ```
>   const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t size);
> ```
>
> This  function  converts the network address structure src in the af address family into a character string.

`size` describes the size of memory `dst` points to.

I understand the use of `socklen_`t in other functions like `connect()` or `accept()`.

But why is `socklen_t` used here?-S

This should be `size_t`!

Comment: `getnameinfo()` also uses `socklen_t`.  `size_t` is defined to be at least 16bit.  `socklen_t` is defined to be at least 32bit. So any `size_t` value can fit in a `socklen_t`.  `socklen_t` is just an opaque integer type defined in [`socket.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html), so it is related to socket APIs, whereas `size_t` is related more to the C/C++ language itself.

Comment: From [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html): `CONFORMING TO POSIX.1-2001.  Note that RFC 2553 defines a prototype where the last argument size is of type size_t.  Many systems follow RFC 2553. Glibc 2.0 and 2.1 have size_t, but 2.2 and later have socklen_t.`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - good answer.  You should move this to the answer section.

Comment: @4566976: Your quote adds even more question marks. (I didn't add this to the question on posting it, to stay as neutral a possible ... :-})